# How to get the last id from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
// Database settings

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.';port='.$dbport.';dbname='.$db.'', $dbuser, $dbpasswd);
?>



<?php
$Name = $_GET['Name'] ;
$FullName = $_GET['FullName'] ;
$Email = $_GET['Email'] ;
$MDP = $_GET['MDP'] ;
$ZipCode = $_GET['ZipCode'] ;
$Country = $_GET['Country'] ;
$Adresse = $_GET['Adresse'] ;
$Phone = $_GET['Phone'] ;



$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO CompteClient(Name,Fullname,Email,MDP,ZipCode,Country,Adresse,Phone) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');

$req->execute(array($Name,$FullName,$Email,$MDP,$ZipCode,$Country,$Adresse,$Phone));
$id = $bdd->lastInsertId();

echo $id;

?>
```

I'm new to php and i try to get the id from the last row i insert
I tried everything i saw on the forum but everytime i get somes errors

Comment: The `execute` method returns either true or false depending whether it was successful - you can use that to initially test for the success of the statement before trying to get the `lastInsertId` - what errors are you getting though is important.

Comment: Whenever you get an error, always post that when asking a question here

Comment: i tried this : if ($req->execute(array($Name,$FullName,$Email,$MDP,$ZipCode,$Country,$Adresse,$Phone)) == true) {
    $id = $bdd->lastInsertId();
} and it work thanks for help ^^

Comment: You probably also ought to find out why the query failed and fix it, because that should be an incredibly rare event and really something you should be able to fix during development, without needing extra checks which persist in the code. (You can of course turn on PDO's exception handling as a backstop so that if an error _does_ occur, you'd see it and be able to log it for investigation